# what linux command can can add new filed key value pair to a json file

Tags: json, linux, bash, command-line

I have a json file in a directory and I need to replace the value of a key, add a new value key paire. The json file is in this form:

```
{

  "Name" : "username",

  "Actionchecked" : {
    "Enablecheck" : true,
    "savecheck" : true,
  },

  "User" : {
    //"user" : "pass"
  }

}
```

How can I add or append new key value "Authentication" and "newuser" for my json to look like that?

```
{

  "Name" : "username",

  "Actionchecked" : {
    "Enablecheck" : true,
    "savecheck" : true
  },

  "Authentication" : {
    "foo" : true,
    "poo" : false

  "User" : {
    //"user" : "pass"
    "newuser" : newpass"
  }
}
```

I know using sed I can replace value of Name as follow in the file.json

```
sudo sed -i -- 's/"Name" : "Name1"/"Name" : "username"/g' test/file.json
```

Comment: Consider using `jq` tool

Comment: `sed` or any other tool that processes text without understanding its content **cannot** be safely used to process JSON. Try [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq).

Comment: BTW, "StackSnippets" are for code that can be run in a browser (which is why they create "Run code snippet" buttons). Use the `{}` button, not the "Create Snippet" button, for code samples that aren't HTML+JavaScript+CSS.

Comment: ...also, your code isn't valid JSON -- `//` can't be used as a comment in JSON, for example, and there's a missing `}`. Maybe what you have is actually JavaScript instead?

Comment: (also, some invalid commas; it's hard to actually test an answer's correctness without valid input).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your input JSON is stored in the file `input.json`, this command adds the `Authentication` key and an object value for it and the new key (and a value) inside the object associated to the `User` key:

```
$ jq '.+{Authentication:{foo:true,poo:false}}|.User.newuser="newpass"' input.json
```

The `jq` script, piece by piece:

```
.            # "." is the current item (there is only one object in your input)
+            # "+" is addition; for objects it merges the keys and properties
{Authentication:{foo:true,poo:false}}
             # the object to add to the current item 
|            # pipe the output of the previous filter to the next filter
.User.newuser
             # the "newuser" property of the "User" property of the current item
=            # assign a value to .User.newuser
"newpass"    # the new value to assign to .User.newuser
```

Download `jq` from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ and read about how to use it at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: Particular reason to be using `+=` rather than, say, `.newuser="newpass"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no reason, I was probably influenced by the `+` used above. Thank you for the suggestion, the script is simpler this way.

Comment: @axiac thanks. I will definitely check the jq documentation. Speaking of the example, this does not seem to update the json file. Instead it display it to the bash with no change in the file.

Comment: `jq` works as a filter. It gets its data from a file or from `stdin`, operates on it then outputs the result. You can redirect its output to a file as you usually do in shell commands. Just don't try to redirect it to the input file or you'll lose its content.

Comment: @ludo : The typical form to update a file with *nix filters is `cmd file > tmpFile && /bin/mv tmpFile`. The `&&` insures that the old file is only replaced with `tmpFile` if there were no error reported running `cmd`. BUT, until you're really good at things, it better to keep your original files, so you can retrace your steps, so `cmd file > betterFile && /bin/mv file file.orig` might be more appropriate. Good luck.